# Is there a way to detect if a browser window is closed?

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to detect if a browser window is closed using GWT. For example a window opened through GWT using this code:

```
Window.open("some_url", "__blank", null);
```

I need to detect wether this windows opened through gwt is closed. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804118/how-to-create-one-database-connection-per-user-on-a-java-servlet-application/6804785#6804785

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it is a real problem making it cross-browser.
GWT has

```
 Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {
            public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> windowCloseEvent) {

            }
        });
```

Which handles the `onunload` event(occurs before the browser closes the document).
However it does not work for handling browser close event with all browsers, because when refreshing the page, this event is fired as well.

Since GWT also generates JavaScript see this article: [Window Close Event of Browser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58835/Window-Close-Event-of-Browser)
Here is conclusion of that article:

> **Conclusion**
>
> As we have already discussed that there is no 100% fool proof way to
>   detect the browser close event in a lot of cases, the above technique
>   can fail. For example if the user kills the browser's process from
>   task manager, there could be many more cases. Yet in a lot of cases,
>   this technique can be handy. Best of luck and happy programming.

Comment: which is correct, since reloading the page should give you the entier content again, not some leftovers from the last session too...

Comment: @Jamshid Why cross browser? Isn't a new window can open any kind of page (there's no cross browser issue with that?) Is that what you mean?

Comment: Opening is the same in all browsers, but you cannot differentiate between refreshing a window and closing the browser. both events are handled by `onUnload` event.